# Create Graph from sqlite using calendar as X axis

Tags: android, sqlite, android-graphview

I want to create a graph calendar versus integer. Either key in date format in the table or parse the string value to date.

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.helper.DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class VIewGraph extends AppCompatActivity {

    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;
    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_graph);
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        String y;
        Float z;
        Date d1;
        Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.readEntry();
        int rows = data.getCount();
        data.moveToFirst();

        GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph11);
        series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();

        for(int i = 0;  i <rows; i++){
            data.moveToNext();
            String x = data.getString(2);
            y = data.getString(3);
            z = Float.parseFloat(y);   
            Date date1;
            try { 
                date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(x);
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                  }

            series.appendData(new DataPoint(date1, z), true, 25);
        }
        graph.addSeries(series);

        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(3);
        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHumanRounding(false);

    }
}
```

Here is some code regarding the getTime()

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.icu.util.Calendar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.sql.Time;

public class Logging extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "Logging";

DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
EditText editWeight, editFat, editHydration, editMuscle, editBone, editTime, editASD;
private Button button2;
private TextView mDisplayDate, mDisplayTime;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_logging);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    mDisplayTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);

    editWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editWeight);
    editFat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFat);
    editHydration = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editHydration);
    editMuscle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMuscle);
    editBone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editBone);

    mDisplayDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    Logging.this,
                    android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                    mDateSetListener,
                    year,month,day);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.show();

        }
    });

    mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            month = month + 1;
            Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet: mm/dd/yyyy: " + day + "/" + month + "/" + year);

            String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            mDisplayDate.setText(date);
        }
    };

    mDisplayTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View view) {
                                            Calendar mTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                                            int mHour = mTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                                            int mMinute = mTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                                            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(Logging.this,
                                                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                                                              int minute) {

                                                            mDisplayTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                                                        }
                                                    }, mHour, mMinute, true);
                                            timePickerDialog.show();
                                        }
                                    });

    LogData();
}

public void LogData(){
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean isInserted = mDatabaseHelper.addData(
                    mDisplayDate.getText().toString(),
                    mDisplayTime.getText().toString(),
                    editWeight.getText().toString(),
                    editFat.getText().toString(),
                    editHydration.getText().toString(),
                    editMuscle.getText().toString(),
                    editBone.getText().toString()
            );
            if (isInserted == true)
                Toast.makeText(Logging.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(Logging.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Now the error is here on Logcat:

08-19 21:58:50.313 25858-25858/example.christopher.bd E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: example.christopher.bd, PID: 25858
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{example.christopher.bd/example.christopher.bd.VIewGraph}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference
        at com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint.(DataPoint.java:45)
        at example.christopher.bd.VIewGraph.onCreate(VIewGraph.java:48)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Can anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: The error in your latest code is in getTime() function. Can you post the code where getTime() is written?

Comment: edited on the getTime() function

Comment: bro, there is no getTime() in your code..

Comment: is it different with Calendar.getInstance()?

Comment: Yes.. You have used date.getTime() somewhere.. Or else Paste your full activity code.. I'll check

Comment: I edited the activity on the activity where I choose the date. If you need the databasehelper I can also provide the code.

Comment: Check out my new answer below:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

`Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(x);`

To:

```
   Date date1 = null;
   try { 
        date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(x);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This should solve your issue.

**Parse** requires it to be under try catch as **Parse** doesn't know what kind of string will be supplied to it.

Comment: It said that "variable date1 might not been initialized" in the line
series.appendData(new DataPoint(date1, z), true, 25);

Comment: If the previous error was solved by this answer, please accept it for others to know..

Answer (score 0):

See in the ViewGraph Activity file in import statements:

```
import java.sql.Time; // Delete this line
```

Write this line:

```
import java.util.Time;
```

This will work now.

Comment: u meant in Logging.java file?
I changed it but it said 'cannot resolve symbol Time'

Comment: Yes, then left-click on Time (cannot solve symbol) and then alt+enter then import java.util.Time

Comment: Still can't. In my original code, java.sql.Time is colored gray (unused import statement) which means I didn't use that line right? I deleted it and nothing changed actually. 

I also can't write import java.util.Time;